# jQuery fade in background image on hover

Tags: jquery

I have a row of menu buttons, and I need the background-image to be transparent, and then fade in on rollover (hover).
can I use jQuery to acheive this?

http://jsfiddle.net/craigzilla/JdHWY/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is not possible to fade background only while text in the block is visible, you can make small changes in the markup:

HTML:

```
<div class="menuitem"><span></span>ITEM 01</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuitem {
    position: relative;
    /* ... */
}
.menuitem span {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-image: url(http://thumbs.gograph.com/gg58916312.jpg);
    z-index: -1;
}​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".menuitem").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("span").fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).children("span").fadeOut();
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JdHWY/11/

Comment: Do you have any idea why the jsfiddle doesn't work when I try paste it in a HTML file?
http://www.craigzilla.dk/royalarena/menu.html

Comment: +1 for good method, but could be improved by using `:before` or `:after` instead of a `span` and relying on CSS3 `opacity` transitions rather than jQuery.

Comment: @Ennui Then why not to use CSS transitions instead? `;)`

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
  <div class="header">
    <div class="menuitem">ITEM 01</div>
    <div class="menuitem">ITEM 02</div>
    <div class="menuitem">ITEM 03</div>
    <div class="menuitem">ITEM 04</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuitem {
    background-image: url(http://thumbs.gograph.com/gg58916312.jpg);
    width: 180px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-top: 102px;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 85px;
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.menuitem').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 300);
});
```

See the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JdHWY/20/)**

Comment: Why don't you use `.stop()` ?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, but is it possible to only fade the background-image and not the text?

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen I update my fiddle and I think animate backgroud image is not possible

Answer (score 0):

It is something like this (top of my head) and then you've have to add fadin() fadeout() to the mix for instance.

http://jsfiddle.net/JdHWY/4/

Answer (score 0):

#### *[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/LN8Yj/)*

```
$('.menuitem').fadeTo(0,0.7).on('mouseenter mouseleave',function( ev ){
    ev=ev.type==='mouseenter'      ?  // event is mouseenter?
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(200,1)   :  // (if yes) 
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(200,0.7) ;  // (if no) event is mouseleave
});
```

This will handle pretty well mustiple-fast mouseovers thanks to `.stop()` that will clear animations queue.